# get disk_space with credentials

Tags: php, diskspace, unc, networkcredentials

Well, what I am trying to do is, to get space information of disks in a LAN. I stored the UNC Paths in a XML-File and loop through it.

In PHP I do:

```
$filename = 'C:/...../config/config.xml';
echo '<div class="container">';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);

    foreach($xml->children() as $Path) {
        foreach($Path->children() as $Path1) {
           $disk = disk_total_space($Path1);
.
.
```

This works very well actually, but when I try to get information of disk in a another network, it fails. So when I connect via UNC-Path on windows (with username and password) first, then it works, because now I have access. I can map network disks, but that's not a good solution for me, because there are to many disk.

Now my question is, is there a way to pass username and passwort to the UNC-Path?

Answer (score 0):

Install your Web Server as a service and set the appropriate credentials in: 
**Log On** >> **This account**
Provide valid **username** and **password** (credentials that has access to UNC-Path) and restart your Web Server.

Comment: But I have to use more than one credential. That means I have many disk with different credentials.

Comment: the only way to achieve that is to create a new user in your different networks :( ...